# how to show description under choies in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to show small description under choies like this image,
in front to need to pass this value to show description,any can help me

[image]

my model is

```
from django.db import models
from sqlalchemy import true
from company.models import Company
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


WORK_PLACE_TYPE =(
        ('onsite',' On-site'),
        ('hybrid','Hybrid'),
        ('remote','Remote'),
)
class Job(models.Model):
    

    company =models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE);
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=true)
    workplace_type = models.CharField(max_length=32 , choices=WORK_PLACE_TYPE ,default='onsite',)
    experience =models.CharField(max_length=400)
    skills =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location =models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} '.format(self.title,self.company,self.location)
```

Any hint how to do this.